# Blender not saving new orientation after applying all transforms when saving as .OBJ file

Tags: mesh, export, import, obj

I am new-ish to blender so I am hoping this is an easy mistake and not a bug.

I am creating basic 3d meshes in the Blender GUI and saving each as an obj file. However, they need to be rotated 90 degrees first to be flat against the background since I was using a different coordinate system previously. I have tried setting the rotation manually so it looks like this:
[image: Transform Window showing X=90, Y=0, Z=0]

Next I use the apply transform function to zero-out the values while keeping the orientation.
[image: Select Object->ctrl-a->all transforms]

This works and it looks like it is zero-ed out:  [image: Transform Window showing X=0, Y=0, Z=0]

When I save the blender project and then export the object as a .OBJ file the orientation doesn't stick. If I re-load the object into blender it looks like it is the correct orientation but it say it is oriented at X=90, Y=0, Z=0 again as if I had never zero-ed it out.

Any idea what could be happening? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender rotates the object after importing it because the standard for MOST graphics applications(but not blender) is to have the Y axis as up, instead of the Z axis.

Because of this, when blender exports .obj files(and other formats too), it switches the y and z axes to be compatible. When it imports them it switches them again in order to preserve the intended orientation.

This behavior can be changed in the export settings, but then it may not look the way it should in other applications.

Blender likely does not apply the rotations to the object when importing so you, the user, can tell what the actual values were in the .obj file.

Comment: Nit: It's not the standard for _most_ graphics applications to have Y up.  In my experience it's about 50 / 50 depending on in what domain the application oriented.  GIS, for example is almost uniformly Z up, because that's how the world works.

Comment: Even if I set all rotations to 0 after import and the mesh looks correct in the viewer, and then on export I set forward and up axis as I see them in the viewer, the orientation still gets lost after export and re-import.

Comment: I think that the trick is to apply the transform as OP notes, but leave import and export axes orientations as blenders defaults.

Answer (score 3):

OBJ files do not contain transform information. The rotation after importing comes from the "Transform" import options, which performs axis conversion. The default one (-Z Forward, Y Up) always results in a X=90, Y=0, Z=0 rotation.